# Split String if it contains Tab between characters

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a `String` similar to this:

`2.34   3.80    2.65    1.49    1.27    1.60    0   1.80    0   2.01    4.5 1.80    2.01`

I want to split each of them and add into some Array. But how to split them if there is no space between them, but they are splitted by Tab? I tried:

```
String.Replace(" ", ";").Split(";")
```

I also tried:

```
String.Split("\")
```

it didn't work neither.

It seems that my string doesn't contain `Space` between each data.

So now I am confused how to split them, if there is Tab between them?

Comment: Maybe you can try to replace all whitespace to a single space or any special characters by using System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str,@"\s+"," "); after that use String.Split('your special character or single splace')

Comment: If there is Tab between them then you can use `str.Split('\t')`

Comment: Just split on tabs: `var items = MyString.Split('\t');`

Comment: or look into regex.split() that lets you split on full strings :)